# Gunn vs. VCO in terms of phase noise and THD

Tags: rf, oscillator

I am trying to compare the THD and noise phase of a Gunn oscillator and a VCO. I conducted an experiment where I measured both parameters for both devices and came up with the following results:

(1) THD: VCO's was 4.03%; Gunn's was 14.3%

(2) Noise phase: VCO's was between -85 dBc/Hz at 10kHz and -110 dBc/Hz at 100kHz; Gunn's was -70.8 dBc/Hz at 50kHz.

It should be noted that the Gunn was operating at about 8.6GHz whereas the VCO at about 1.6GHz. Also, the Gunn was connected to the SA using a 10dB attenuator.

Here's what I am unsure of - why are the VCO's THD and noise phase significantly lower than those of the Gunn? Is it because the Gunn's central frequency was much higher?

Furthermore, is it to be expected that the precision and stability of the VCO will be better than those of the Gunn?

I'd appreciate some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Per Leeson equation, using the same Q for two oscillators, the higher frequency
oscillator will have more phase noise, given all else is the same.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leeson%27s_equation

Then we have the Gunn installed in a cavity, with coupling efficiencies different from direct L+C resonator connections into the VCO.

Comment: Thank you. How may I know if the Q's are indeed similar? Don't they vary greatly from one another? In such case and under these constraints (measurements carried out at different frequencies etc.), how may I compare the THD and phase noise of the two? Also, what about the precision and stability? The precision of the Gunn was found to be 0.0066% and its stability 570kHz, but these parameters were not checked for the VCO. I presume that due to the frequency difference the precision and stability of the Gunn will be better. Is that a correct assumption to make?